# Hive UDF with date incrementing

Tags: java, hive, hiveql, user-defined-functions, unix-timestamp

I am attempting to write a user defined function that will allow you to input a date(current_date) and a range and the query will return the following dates along with how many dates have passed. As example if given current_date, query will return current_date - 0 day, next_day - 1 day. 
I have been trying different date types(unixtimestamp, date, jodatime, localdatetime). I scrapped my previous code and am really just hoping for some insight on the problem and less code.

Comment: Maybe sharing some of your code can actually help you in this case.

Comment: With [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) I don’t think it should be too hard. In any case it’s the class you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using pure Hive query:

```
set hivevar:start_date=2019-01-02; 
set hivevar:end_date=2019-01-31;  

with date_range as 
(--this query generates date range
select date_add ('${hivevar:start_date}',s.i) as dt, s.i days
  from ( select posexplode(split(space(datediff('${hivevar:end_date}','${hivevar:start_date}')),' ')) as (i,x) ) s
)

select dt, days from date_range;
```

Returns:

```
dt  days    
2019-01-02  0   
2019-01-03  1   
2019-01-04  2   
2019-01-05  3   
2019-01-06  4   
2019-01-07  5   
2019-01-08  6   
2019-01-09  7   
2019-01-10  8   
2019-01-11  9   
2019-01-12  10  
2019-01-13  11  
2019-01-14  12  
2019-01-15  13  
2019-01-16  14  
2019-01-17  15  
2019-01-18  16  
2019-01-19  17  
2019-01-20  18  
2019-01-21  19  
2019-01-22  20  
2019-01-23  21  
2019-01-24  22  
2019-01-25  23  
2019-01-26  24  
2019-01-27  25  
2019-01-28  26  
2019-01-29  27  
2019-01-30  28  
2019-01-31  29
```

Hope you got the idea.

Comment: this worked perfectly, I still need to configure it for my problem but it does what is needed. thank you very much for your help.